# Communicating with Rails application via POST after OmniAuth authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, omniauth

Hi I'm creating a project in which I use OmniAuth to authenticate a user. Its working correctly, except in my application I would like to send information to the server via javascript using POST.

However when I debug the application, I notice it cannot find the user if I send a request using POST - (I believe also the request.env["omniauth.auth"] variable does not exist according when I browsed at the breakpoint).

I'm outputting some debug information back to the application via JSON. 
When I change the XMLHttpRequest to use GET, it works and I get back the correct information.

What is the correct usage, perhaps I have an incorrect route? I'm also not sure about using '_method' - would that help? Maybe I'm just looking in the wrong direction period?

How can I send via POST in javascript after authentication with OmniAuth and still retrieve the current_user

Comment: If I turn off protect_from_forgery it does return valid info using POST if that sheds some light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue lies in the way protect_from_forgery works. What you'll have to do is validate that your request is safe and the forgery protection should be ignored, you can do this by implementing the forgery_whitelist? at your ApplicationController class:

```
def forgery_whitelist?
  request.user_agent ~= /iPhone/ || self.current_user || super
end
```

At this method you can implement the logic to whitelist a request and make Rails ignore the forgery protection.